# Google analytics page view url duplicates

Tags: web, google-analytics

In my Google Analytics stats i get two lines related to one url like with different stats

/my-page | xxx views
/my-page/ | xxxx views

So the question is, are they counted as different pages and statistics of each link is completely unique and does not affect views of the other one, or when visiting first link, views of the second one also increments and vice versa?

Also is this normal behavior or i can somehow reduce stats only to one url? For the first one, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytics treats them as two different pages, so the stats are independent of each other.
To consider the aggregate statistics in Analytics you can make a filter that includes those 2 pages and look at the row of totals.